# td:contains search string in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to search a table cell which contains a string. The following code works perfectly fine:

```
var allrows = $("#usersTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
$(allrows[j]).find('td:contains("abc")'))
```

But this does not:

```
var allrows = $("#usersTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
var mystring = "abc"
$(allrows[j]).find('td:contains(mystring)'))
```

The only difference is in the second case I am storing the search string in a variable.

Comment: try this $(allrows[j]).find('td:contains('+mystring+')')

Comment: string concat you are adding a var now if you dont add `++` it will be looking of td which contains `mystring` not `abc`

Comment: Awesome! this worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String concatenation:

```
   $(allrows[j]).find('td:contains('+mystring+')')
```

Comment: Does td:contains give me output with the cell having the exact string? or cell which contains the string? I mean if one cell has abc and other has abcd and the other having abcd fg will I get all rows or just the row with abc? (if I am looking for abc)

Answer (score 1):

You need look like this

```
var allrows = $("#usersTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
var mystring = "abc"
$(allrows[j]).find('td:contains('+ mystring +')');
```